# How to determine query performance on basis of Index(a,b)

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

How to rank these queries performance wise?

> The problem is, Given Index(a,b) and 4 queries.
>
> 1. Select * from user where a = 0 AND b = 0.
> 2. Select * from user where a = 0 OR  b = 0.
> 3. Select * from user where a > 0 AND b = 0.
> 4. Select * from user where a = 0 AND b > 0.
>
> Which query runs fastest and which is least efficient.

How to determine it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine which query will be theoretically faster/slower you can look into how database index works: it is essentially tree build from values from a column first, then appended with values from b column

Some notes:

Looking for exact value is faster neither looking for range (like > 0), just because you need to scan less data.

It means that query will perform faster for conditions, where both variable compared to const:

1. Select * from user where a = 0 AND b = 0

Second type of query is first column in index has const comparison and second one is range, as again you reduce number of scans (you don't need to scan Bs for A != 0):

2. Select * from user where a = 0 AND b > 0

Next query partially scans A range (this is why it is slower than 1/2), but can quite quickly match b:

3. Select * from user where a > 0 AND b = 0

Last one is where you have OR, basically you do 2 separate scans and then merge results (or just perform full scan):

4. Select * from user where a = 0 OR b = 0

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one doubt, since our index is of type (a,b), and for (a = 0 and b >0) we have constant a and also we have index build first by a that's why it is faster than (a >0 and b=0). Also for (a = 0 or b = 0), both a and b are constants so shouldn't it be rank 2nd. can you explain the merging part which happens in case of OR. @llya Bursov

Comment: @ajourney OR condition means that we cannot use const for A comparison, as we also want rows where b ==0, but a is not 0

Comment: ok, thanks. I understood it. basically 4 is merging 2nd and 3rd. Thanks for help. can you please tell the explanation i gave above for a > 0 and b = 0 is right or not.

Answer (score 2):

Like Ilya says, plus...

```
where a > 0 AND b = 0
```

will only partially use `INDEX(a,b)`; the `b` part of the index will be unused.  `INDEX(b,a)` would be good for that `where`.

One way to improve the performance of `OR` is to split it into two `SELECTs` and `UNION` them together:

```
(SELECT * FROM t WHERE a=0)
UNION ALL  -- or DISTINCT if you need de-dupping
(SELECT * FROM t WHERE b=0)
```

More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql